# 'or' in elif ignores else statement and closes loop

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

Really confused by the difference in behavior between the two following scripts

test.py

```
while True:
    print 'Enter commands, blah blah'
    input = raw_input(">> ") #get keyboard input
    if (input == 'string'):
        print '\n' #whatever task
    elif (input == 'quit'):
        exit()  #exits the application
    else:
        print 'Invalid'
```

test2.py

```
while True:
    print 'Enter commands, blah blah'
    input = raw_input(">> ") #get keyboard input
    if (input == 'string'):
        print '\n' #whatever task
    elif (input == 'quit' or 'exit'):
        exit()  #exits the application
    else:
        print 'Invalid'
```

Here's the result if you run both of these scripts

```
bred@loaf:~/py$ python test.py
Enter commands, blah blah
>> a
Invalid
Enter commands, blah blah
>> quit
bred@loaf:~/py$ python test2.py
Enter commands, blah blah
>> a
bred@loaf:~/py$
```

As you can see, test.py works as expected, but test2.py exits immediately rather than performing the else statement. Very confused, the only difference between the two scripts is the "or 'exit'" in the elif statement.

Comment: `'exit'` is always true. Try it: `if 'exit': print 'hello'`; you'll see that it prints `hello` 100% of the time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-b-or-c-or-d-always-evaluate-to-true is perhaps an even better duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You should change:

```
    elif (input == 'quit' or 'exit'):
```

to:

```
    elif (input == 'quit' or input == 'exit'):
    #                     ---^---
```

otherwise `exit` evaluate as `True` like any (non-empty) string.

Comment: even better: `input in ['quit', 'exit']`